# How to get Package Version being used in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know if there is a way to get the version of a specific package.

For example, how can I fetch which version of `Provider` package I am using?

EDIT:
Just to be clear, I have an app and I want to know the version of OTHER packages that my app is using programmatically.

Comment: I also want to do this so that I can show the current version of my package from my example app without having to remember to update a hard-coded value every time.

Answer (score 2):

Include your project's `pubspec.yaml` as an asset in your Flutter app and introspect it at runtime with the [`pubspec_parse`](https://pub.dev/packages/pubspec_parse) package via [`Pubspec.parse`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pubspec_parse/latest/pubspec_parse/Pubspec/Pubspec.parse.html).

Comment: Do you know how to use it? Is that `String yaml` the path for the yaml file? Documentation is poor

Comment: whatever I try to pass as the first argument I get: `ParsedYamlException: line 1, column 1: Not a map`

Comment: The `yaml` parameter expects the raw text of a YAML document. You can load the string content of an asset using the Flutter services package [`loadString` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle/loadString.html).

Answer (score -2):

Import https://pub.dev/packages/package_info/ into your application.

Just follow the instructions on there and you should be good to go.

Here is a tutorial that will walk you through that

https://blog.maskys.com/how-to-get-the-version-build-number/

Comment: I thought about saying that `package_info` does not solve my issue. Unless there is a way to fetch for example `provider` package version that I don't know. But if you read the question I want to find out the version of OTHER packages that I have in my app.

Comment: So you are wanting to display the pubspec.yaml version data of your dependencies?  Or are you wanting to query all of the packages that are installed and get the data that way?  If you just wanted to grab the pubspec data then you could use PubSpecCheck... the other way I am not sure of way... nor would I think it would be a good idea... could be wrong.  I am probably just dense and not understanding your question.

Comment: let's say I have a remote list with all the packages and the latest versions. I want to be able check my packages to see if I have a new update to make or if there is a new major version on a package I use.
Is it more clear now? I don't know how to express better than: `know the version of OTHER packages that my app is using, programmatically`

Answer (score -2):

try flutter pub outdated you will see the current version, upgradable version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).